# Merge two dataframes with uncertainty on keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to use 'merge' to combine two data frames with shape:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID1':[10,32,53,65,3],'A':[1,4,2,5,4],'B':[3,5,2,9,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID2':[68,35,93,5,23],'A':[9,5,3,7,4],'B':[6,5,1,9,3]})
```

Those looks as follows:

```
In [29]: df1
Out[29]: 
   ID1  A  B
0   10  1  3
1   32  4  5
2   53  2  2
3   65  5  9
4    3  4  3

In [32]: df2
Out[32]: 
   ID2  A  B
0   68  9  6
1   35  5  5
2   93  3  1
3    5  7  9
4   23  4  3
```

What I am looking for is to merge columns 'A' and 'B' with a defined uncertainty. For example + - 0.5. I don't have clear how to handle this. What I was trying to do is to manually add an uncertainty:

```
df1['Al'] = (np.around(df1['A']+ 0.5, decimals=1))
df1['Bl'] = (np.around(df1['B']+ 0.5, decimals=1))
df1['Ar'] = (np.around(df1['A']- 0.5, decimals=1))
df1['Br'] = (np.around(df1['B']- 0.5, decimals=1))
df2['Al'] = (np.around(df2['A']+ 0.5, decimals=1))
df2['Bl'] = (np.around(df2['B']+ 0.5, decimals=1))
df2['Ar'] = (np.around(df2['A']- 0.5, decimals=1))
df2['Br'] = (np.around(df2['B']- 0.5, decimals=1))
```

After this, I do the merge:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['A','B','Al','Bl','Ar','Br'], right_index=True, how='outer', indicator='all')
```

But here I got stuck because I can not figure it out how to use a conditional merge. The idea is to merge all those rows were columns 'A' and 'B' be the same with a definite certainty

The expected output would be:

```
df3:
   ID1  A  B  ID2  A  B
1  32   4  5  35   5  5
2  53   2  2  93   3  1
4  3    4  3  23   4  3
```

Comment: Can you add some data that will yield some successful joins and unsuccessful joins along with your expected output from this data?

Comment: can you add the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Simple but expensive

Just do a Cartesian product then select down rows you want.  This will work well for smaller data sets but will be very expensive on large data sets

```
dfs = (df1.assign(foo=1).merge(df2.assign(foo=1), on="foo", suffixes=("","_df2"))
 .assign(adiff=lambda x: x["A"]-x["A_df2"])
 .assign(bdiff=lambda x: x["B"]-x["B_df2"])
 .query("adiff>=-1 and adiff<=1 and bdiff>=-1 and bdiff<=1")
 .drop(columns=["adiff","bdiff","foo"])
)

print(dfs.to_string(index=False))
```

#### output

```
 ID1  A  B  ID2  A_df2  B_df2
  32  4  5   35      5      5
  53  2  2   93      3      1
   3  4  3   23      4      3
```

Nearest value match is provided by [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)

1. can only match on one column and it must be ordered
2. if's a left join so choose which data frame you want to drive it
3. it's fairly common to calculate a value which is used as join.  This is represented in second approach below. In GIS / GPS use cases it's typically distance - hence reason I named column *d*
4. first example is doing two merges, first on *A* then on *B*.  You have all the data together and can then do further logic

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID1':[10,32,53,65,3],'A':[1,4,2,5,4],'B':[3,5,2,9,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID2':[68,35,93,5,23],'A':[9,5,3,7,4],'B':[6,5,1,9,3]})


# find nearest row in df2 when matching on columns A or B
dfmab = pd.merge_asof(
    (pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values("A"), df2.sort_values("A"), 
                   on="A", direction="nearest", suffixes=("","_Adf2"))
    ).sort_values("B") 
    ,df2.sort_values("B"),
    on="B", direction="nearest", suffixes=("","_Bdf2")
)

# calculate a value that represents value of row
dfmd = pd.merge_asof(
    df1.assign(d=lambda x: x["A"]*x["B"]).sort_values("d"),
    df2.assign(d=lambda x: x["A"]*x["B"]).sort_values("d"),
    on="d", direction="nearest", suffixes=("","_Ddf2")
)

print(dfmab.to_string(index=False))
print(dfmd.to_string(index=False))
```

**output**

```
 ID1  A  B  ID2  B_Adf2  ID2_Bdf2  A_Bdf2
  53  2  2   93       1        93       3
  10  1  3   93       1        23       4
   3  4  3   23       3        23       4
  32  4  5   23       3        35       5
  65  5  9   35       5         5       7
 ID1  A  B   d  ID2  A_Ddf2  B_Ddf2
  10  1  3   3   93       3       1
  53  2  2   4   93       3       1
   3  4  3  12   23       4       3
  32  4  5  20   35       5       5
  65  5  9  45   68       9       6
```

Comment: Glad it makes sense - I've provided an update that is a very simple solution but won't scale...